# Adding AppStore link to Facebook published from iOS device clears name / caption / description

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So if I make a request on Facebook via my iOS device with the params:

[image: params with link to app on app store]

Then the post appears on my wall as such:

[image: Post without info]

But when I DON'T include the app store link in the params the post appears as it should:

[image: params with link to website and not app store]

[image: The post the way I want it to look]

I have no idea why it does this, is there any way I can have all of the information and when clicked it goes to the App Store?

Comment: When you include the link we use the og-tags on the link.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the post force-use my supplied params?

Comment: Or rather, is there a way @WizKid that I can make my post look like the second example but click through to the app store instead?